# Eclipse PyDev has quit recognizing QGIS objects

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, eclipse

I followed the instructions for setting up Eclipse with PyDev to start creating QGIS plug ins found here: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html

after doing that I was able to create a QGIS plugin and it works as intended, but when I opened the project this morning eclipse no longer recognizes the QgsPoint or QgsRaster objects, and is now putting it's standard red line under them to I have checked

> > Window > Preferences > PyDev> Interpreters > Python

and made sure that **Libraries** still contains the QGIS and QGIS plugin references and that **Force Builtins** still contains *qgis*

This problem does not seem to be altering my ability to modify the code. I can change the code, and after a reload QGIS will run the plugin with the changes I make.

I would like to know how to get eclipse+PyDev to recognize the QGIS objects again so that I can get rid of the red lines and focus on actual errors while debugging.

Update:

The plot thickens. This screen shot was taken with my mouse hovering over the pixelData0 object and it clearly shows that Eclipse can resolve it to a layers.dataProvider.identify object from  QGISRasterLayerCreation so Eclipse clearly can see some of the QGIS objects, but if you look at the same line the QgsPoint reference is being underlined in red. When I hover over it the error message says *Undefined Variable: QgsPoint*

[image: PyDev-Eclipse-QGIS-Weirdness]